# Unable to Install Platforms for Android SDK r15

Tags: android, installation

I have downloaded and unzipped the file android-sdk_r15-windows.zip from the 
URL  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html,  however the install instructions 
I have installed the SDK and the ADT plugin for eclipse as described with no hitches, however when I go to create a new AVD using the AVD Manager.exe that came with the install archive there are no targets.  This seems to be because i haven't installed any platforms into my system.  This is where the question comes.  All the install instructions and tutorials refer to executables,  1) SDK setup.exe and 2) Android SDK and AVD Manager,  neither of these applications came with the install zip described above.  There are however 2 files SDK Manager.exe and AVD Manager.exe.  So without the tools described ongline it seems impossible to install the platforms into the SDK,  does anyone know where these tools went or how to install platforms into my system using the SDK Manager or AVD Manager

---

**[Edit]**

Here is an image of what I am describing,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the root of the sdk zip file, there is an SDK Manager executable. If you run that, you can use it to select which platforms you want to download and install. Don't forget to install the platform-tools package as well.

The image below shows the available package screen within the manager:
[image]

Comment: When I use this tool,  there is nothing that allows me to select platforms,  A single window opens which shows a selection for packages.  However under the packages the only thing that is visible is the following.  Tools > Android SDK Tools (R15, Installed) > Extra > nothing under here

Comment: did you try selecting "available packages" and then expanding the Android Repository tree?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. 
I have followed following steps.

1. Uninstall above installation from Eclips
2. Follow steps as described into the link: http://sochinda.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-install-android-sdk-offline-not-completely-offline/#comment-428