# Unable to install platforms/USB driver for Android r15

Tags: android, installation

First of all, I'm a student that wants to work with Android for my internship. Here is a link about my upcoming question, but he did not get a good awnser yet: [Unable to Install Platforms for Android SDK r15](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8040288)

After reading some about android I started the download and install. I got a SDK manager and a AVD manager. Got eclipse etc too. But no SDK and AVD manager like I see everywhere on the internet. I searched everywhere and I can install some things manually, but that isn't handy.

So with my SDK manager I cannot download the platforms I want. Maybe I need to download an older reversion of the SDK, so I get the SKD and AVD manager instead of seperated.

Please take a look at the link. Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

Anyone got a solution for downloading the platforms/Google USB driver/etc.. in the SDK program itself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you installed the SDK manager into the eclipse with a install new software method as spefified in the android developer installation files.

```
Downloading the ADT Plugin

Use the Update Manager feature of your Eclipse installation to install the latest revision of ADT on your development computer.<>

Assuming that you have a compatible version of the Eclipse IDE installed, as described in Preparing for Installation, above, follow these steps to download the ADT plugin and install it in your Eclipse environment.

    Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
    Click Add, in the top-right corner.
    In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

    Click OK

    Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
    In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
    In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
    Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

    Note: If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
    When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```

after that ... you can can install the SDK  from [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)... now in the eclipse open the preferences --> Android. specify the path to your SDK root directory... that is it... now press the ADT plugin icon and then you can download any version you want...

**UPDATE:**
i think the version of eclipse is quite wrong it is better and safer to install the eclipse classic version... the jdk can be decided upon what is you base system. once you have the JDK as 32 or 64 bit download the appropriate eclipse classic version(almost every one does it except with really specific java development{which can be installed/customized any time later}) and helios or indigo i don't think that would matter ... until and unless the ADK supports it. Everything is taken care of by it.

Comment: I allready did those steps, but I did them again. Just take a look at the link that I linked. You can see that my SDK manager looks different from the SKD and AVD manager. For the downloads you say I need to click the ADT plugin icon. But where is the ADT plugin icon?

Comment: yes i understand your concern... let me ask you a few question... what is your base for your system 32bit or 64bit... what installation have you taken for the eclipse... ADT is r15 i understand that.. and windows is your platform.

Comment: thx for your time. I have a 64bit Windows 7 system. The link I downloaded for eclipse is http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-java-indigo-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip But its weird that my SDK managers looks different right?

Comment: I am incidentally having the same machine... at home... now i am testing the method i told you from scratch to end .... will come up with screen shots in the answers update... please give me some 30 mins for it...

Comment: why indigo.... why not helios... i think that is making a different. are you sure when you downloaded that it had compatibility with ADT and android in general.

Comment: I found that out myself too. Android recommends to use the "Eclipse Classic" version. At the moment I'm behind a proxy. I'll test it when im at home on my laptop. Hopefully that works.

Comment: if it works don't forget to rate this as the answer so that other can be well guided.

Comment: Will do :) Fingers crossed that it works on my laptop. Thanks for you effort.

Comment: dont worry it will.. or else come back we will debug it more. and get you up and running with your flavor of android sdk ,,,,,

Comment: I installed the right eclipse now on my laptop. I have no proxy or whatsoever there. So the problem was the proxy and maybe the wrong eclipse too. So thanks for you help!

Comment: proxy are not sometime the problem mostly it is the eclipse version as sometimes the components dont gel properly.